# CRM 2016, OAuth and OData API

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I have an on-premise CRM 2016 system that uses Active Directory and when I attempt to access the OData API from a desktop app, using network credentials, I get an un-authorised message.

After looking into this it would appear that I need to authenticate using OAuth which in turn would require installing AD Federation Services.

Before going down this path I would like to know if this is the correct approach to take?

I've been able to find plenty of examples on how to acheieve this using CRM online/Azure AD, but not much for on-premise 2016.

Comment: 1. Is your desktop app built on .NET framework?

Answer (score 2):

If your desktop app built on .NET framework and runs in the same local network as your CRM server then you can use XRM Tooling SDK instead.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/dn689057%28v%3dcrm.8%29

This SDK lets you create a CrmServiceClient object using a  connection string from your configuration file. This object implements the IOrganization interface which means it has the CRUD methods you can use against your CRM.

```
CrmServiceClient service = new CrmServiceClient(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycrmconnstr"].ConnectionString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the way to make it work with CRM On-Premise.

You will have to install and configure ADFS (according to [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699671.aspx) ADFS 3.0 is the latest version supported). Once everything is set up, the overall process is quite similar to when you're doing it in Online with AAD:

1. [Register application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/dn531010(v=crm.8))

`Add-AdfsClient -ClientId <CLIENT_ID> -Name <APP_NAME> -RedirectUri <REDIRECT_URI>`

2. [Grant application permission to CRM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/adfs/grant-adfsapplicationpermission?view=win10-ps)

`Grant-AdfsApplicationPermission -ClientRoleIdentifier <CLIENT_ID> -ServerRoleIdentifier <CRM_URI>`

3. Connect using [Authorization Code Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1)

Authorization Code is the only flow implemented in ADFS 3.0 (that's why I mentioned it before) so don't waste 4 o 5 hours trying to use `Implicit` like I did :(. ADFS 4.0 implements it (along with `Client Credential` and `Resource Owner Password Credentials` but in theory is not supported (although I've seen it working).

As you said the process is not well documented but you'll find some questions on forums or some blog post that will help you. I found [THIS](https://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/03/09/OAUTH2-Authentication-with-ADFS-3.0.html) one very helpful, even though is not Dynamics related.

Comment: Hi Federico. I've managed to register a client, retrieve an access token and grant permission to the root CRM URL. But, when I access the OData API I still receive an "unauthorized" error even when adding the access token to the Authorization header. The only option I can check that may make a difference is the OAuthClaimsSetting in CRM.

Comment: Have you checked the headers of that response? You should get an authorization url there, is the same you used to get the token from?
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer authorization_uri=URI, Params=string

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crm/2013/12/12/use-oauth-to-authenticate-with-the-crm-service/